# Java HashMap key map doesn't look right

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

Could some one please double check to see what wrong with my code below that would be appreciated.
I tried many times and different ways, but still give me the result which I never expected.

Below is the method which return a Map values

I made 1 called, with pass-in value==0, it works just fine.

-->result works fine, the first key=0 and value correct and all correct.

I made 2nd called with pass-in value=1

-->result is WRONG, the first key==16 where I expected it should be = 12

```
public Map<Integer, String[]> noteNumberNoteNameMap;    
public Map<Integer, String[]> getNoteNumberNoteNameMap(int octave ) {
    noteNumberNoteNameMap = new HashMap<>();
    noteNumberNoteNameMap.put(12*octave+0,  new String[] { "C" });
    noteNumberNoteNameMap.put(12*octave+1,  new String[] { "C#", "Db" });
    noteNumberNoteNameMap.put(12*octave+2,  new String[] { "D" });
    noteNumberNoteNameMap.put(12*octave+3,  new String[] { "D#", "Eb" });
    noteNumberNoteNameMap.put(12*octave+4,  new String[] { "E" });
    noteNumberNoteNameMap.put(12*octave+5,  new String[] { "F" });
    noteNumberNoteNameMap.put(12*octave+6,  new String[] { "F#", "Gb" });
    noteNumberNoteNameMap.put(12*octave+7,  new String[] { "G" });
    noteNumberNoteNameMap.put(12*octave+8,  new String[] { "G#", "Ab" });
    noteNumberNoteNameMap.put(12*octave+9,  new String[] { "A" });
    noteNumberNoteNameMap.put(12*octave+10,  new String[] { "A#", "Bb" });
    noteNumberNoteNameMap.put(12*octave+11,  new String[] { "B" }); 
    return noteNumberNoteNameMap;
}
```

Please advise.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly what the problem is, but keep in mind that `HashMap` has no implicit order. If you need to keep insertion order then use a `LinkedHashMap`. If you need a custom order use a `SortedMap` implementation (e.g. `TreeMap`).

Comment: Take a look at the documentation for [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashMap.html) - note the part where it says _This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map_. Somewhere in your hash map, the key of 12 should exist. It's just not guaranteed to be the first entry you see.

Comment: Hi Slaw, in details, when I called the method like below code:    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {    MyClass mc = new MyClass();   Map<Integer, String[]> test = mc.getNoteNumberNoteNameMap(1);  }  the result "test" Map the first index[0], the key is==16 where I expected it should be 12.  andrewjames: I verified double check, there's no key of 12 exist.  Thank you for answering.

Comment: When I call `getNoteNumberNoteNameMap(1)` using your code, followed by `noteNumberNoteNameMap.get(12)`, it returns a string array containing one entry ("C") - which looks correct to me. Compare this against what you are doing. This is the point about the order not being guaranteed. entry `[0]` is not typically how the data is accessed for a hash map. Use keys instead, as in my example. Or, as @Slaw mentioned, use something which preserves insertion order.

Comment: @LearnNETandJava I suggest you [edit] your question to add a full [mre] demonstrating the problem. Provide sample inputs and outputs and explain the difference between the desired output and the actual output.

Comment: copied and pasted the code into jshell - and `getNoteNumberNoteNameMap(1).get(12)` returns `String[1] { "C" }`. seems to be working as expected

Comment: andrewjames: thank you very much!, I believed you're right, when I debug, the index order not being correct, but the actual result are all good!. thank you all for trying to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HashMap doesn't follow the insertion order. If you want the order to be followed as insertion order, use LinkedHashMap

Comment: Used LinkedHashMap works perfectly as expected!. Thank you Kali and everyone.